# which one is the fastest?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm working on a website which is used on Chrome and IE8. I made it with Javascript and it works fine on Chrome but it is slow on IE.

Is VBScript faster than Javascript on IE? Would I translate my code in VBScript for IE?

Comment: VBScript is old news. Write it in JavaScript.

Comment: In which case it become slow?

Comment: Ok, I trust you @elclanrs thank you !
it becomes slow when I use "For" function with a large quantity of datas...

Comment: IE11 doesn't even support VBScript

Comment: @Geo: none of the Browsers works directly with VBScript unless it is a local file such as vbs executed through shell program, not a website. Read my answer and please take a look at definition of VBScript in W3S school or just google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript is executed for web sites on IIS(web servers), JavaScript mostly on client side.
I do not see how it would not work on any browsers unless you uploading something to client machines as vbs file. That is dangerous and could be considered as security threat - antivirus program may simply block it or delete file all together.

Basically question is not about if VBScript supported or not by any browsers simply because browsers never-ever touching VBScript, but what you attempt to do with VBScript. And anyone who is saying that it does not supported by any browser need to take a lessons from W3S school all over again.

It is different purpose scripting languages on the web: VBScript for servers side processing while JavaScript **mostly** to be used running on client side. And before anyone starts discussing that JavaScript can be used on server side please look what I put in bold letters. There are javascript libraries  AJAX and JQUERY etc. which can be used to process data as well as connecting to web servers.
If you are looking for replacement of VBScript - C# is the best place to start since you already working on Microsoft platform, NET would be logical choice. There is lot of other languages to choose from but you need carefully consider what your project is all about, budget and time needed to rebuild your project/site.

However you can write VBScript and JavaScript batch files for local execution but as I understand that is not part of your question.